# How to align div and span using css

Tags: css

Trying to show dive next of span but it is not working.I do not know how to align. If anyone know please help to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="title">Titles</div>
<span class="icons"> images </span>
</div>
```

app.component.css:

```
  .content{
      width: 100%;
      height:150px; 
     }
    .title{ 
      display:block;
float: right;
border:2px solid #ccc;

}
.icons{

  display:block;
  float: left;
  border:2px solid #ccc;
}
```

expecting:
[image]

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-use-2c9trb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: just use `display: inline-block;` for both and drop the float strategy. By default `span` is an inline element while `div` is a block element. But using `block` is surely wrong if you mean to align elements next to each other

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block`;

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
}
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 4px;
}
.icons {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

and use `direction` and `rtl` to reverse direction of elements

Answer (score 0):

add inline-flex to displays as an inline-level flex container. Then add margin-inline-end to get space between div and span.

```
.content{
width: 100%;
display: inline-flex;
 }

.title{ 
display:block;
float: right;
border:2px solid #ccc;
}

.icons{
display:block;
float: left;
border:2px solid #ccc;
margin-inline-end: 5px;
}
```